# I get the 500 error when I try to return a value from PHP object/array. But it's ok return all the object

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, object

I'm trying to create a simple application in Laravel that sends and gets comments from the database.

I'm using both PHP and JS with AJAX. But when I try to get the full comment object:

PHP

```
    public function UpdateComment(Request $request){
        $id = $request->id;
        $jsonCode = DB::table('comments')->where('id', $id)->get();
        $comment = json_decode($jsonCode);
        return $comment
    }
```

Works well:

```
[{…}]
  0:
   author_id: 6
   comment_date: "2018-09-15 09:53:01"
   comment_text: "23423434234"
   history: ""
   id: 60
   last_update: "2018-09-15 00:00:00"
  >proto__: Object
  length: 1
>proto__: Array(0)
```

This is exactly what I expected to see, the full PHP object.
But when I try to return or simply use a single attribute of this same object, I got a 500 error...

```
return $comment->id;
```

.

```
POST http://laravelhost/update-comment 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I'm a beginner in PHP, so it should be a very simple error.

Comment: json_decode returns an array not an object. Use $comment['id'].

Comment: @RDev I don't knew that... Thank you so much!!

Comment: @RDev It works! Thanks!! Post your Answer so I can finalize this Question. pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error 500 because `json_decode()` returns an array, not an object.
So to access your data use array syntax, instead of object operator:

```
return $comment['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function UpdateComment(Request $request){
    $id = $request->id;
    $record = DB::table('comments')->where('id', $id)->get();
    return $record;
}
```

You don't need to json_decode() the return value of DB::table()... call.

Comment: well, I need to do many other things with those values in the same function. That's why I'm trying to decode.

Comment: DB::table() returns an array and you can return it as is.
You can do many things around it but you shouldn't json_decode() something that is not a json string.

Comment: The return was just a test to verify if the data was getting well. Actually [thats](https://codesandbox.io/s/71w6mj5qy0) the real code .

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a single row you should use first() instead of get()

```
$comment = DB::table('comments')->where('id', $id)->first();
echo $comment->id;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
$comment = DB::table('comments')->where('id', $id)->first();
return $comment->id;
```

or

```
$comment = DB::table('comments')->where('id', $id)->get();
return $comment[0]->id;
```

> If you are using json_decode after fetching data, object will
>   converted to array. So, you have to use **$arrayname['keyname']** for
>   fetching data.